# InfluxDB restore error : updating metadata on influxd service failed

Tags: ubuntu, influxdb

I am having a restore problem with InfluxDB (v 1.7.9). I did a backup on an ubuntu 18.04 machine to be able to export it to another machine with another instance of InfluxDB.

The backup process is OK using the command:

`influxd backup -portable -database db_to_backup /mnt/backup`

After that, I tried to import the database again with the command:

`influxd restore -portable -db db_to_backup -newdb db_test_import /mnt/backup`

I launched this on the same machine and also on the other machine which both have ubuntu 18.04. I get this error:

`restore: updating metadata on influxd service failed: err = read tcp 127.0.0.1:33328->127.0.0.1:8088: read: connection reset by peer, n = 16`

I also launched this restore command on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine and the restore is good.

The "ufw" is disabled and I have exactly the same Influx configuration files on all machines.

**UPDATE 1:**

It is possible to make a backup from the Ubuntu 18 and to import in Ubuntu 16. It is also possible to make a backup from the Ubuntu 16 and to import to an Ubuntu 18 but when I make a backup from the Ubuntu 18 to an Ubuntu 18 version this is where the error occurs.

Comment: what about backup/restore to same influxdb instance? I experience this error even on same influxdb instance

Answer (score 0):

A mix of your two solutions worked for me:

```
sudo influxd restore -portable -database importedDBname -newdb DBtoimporttoname /pathtodump
```